# PyTorch: Differentiable operations to go from coordinate tensor to grid tensor

Tags: pytorch, linear-algebra, gradient-descent

I have a tensor that looks like

```
coords = torch.Tensor([[0, 0, 1, 2],
                       [0, 2, 2, 2]])
```

The first row is the x-coordinates of objects on a grid and the second row is the corresponding y-coordinates.

I need a differentiable way (i.e. gradients can flow) to go from this tensor to the corresponding "grid" tensor, where a 1 represents the presence of an object in that location (row index, column index) and 0 represents no object:

```
grid = torch.Tensor([[1, 0, 1], 
                     [0, 0, 1],
                     [0, 0, 1]])
```

In general, `coords` can be large (the grid size is 300x300). If `coords` was a sparse tensor I could simply call `to_dense` on it, but for various reasons specific to my application I cannot store `coords` as sparse. Additionally, I cannot create a new sparse tensor from `coords` and call `to_dense` on it because creating a new tensor is not differentiable.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Could you be more specific about a _differentiable way to go from this tensor to the corresponding grid tensor_ ?

Comment: By differentiable I mean that the gradients can flow and are not blocked by an operation (like creating a new tensor).

Comment: Okay, so the grid will be input to some neural network and the coords are variables that need to receive gradients from that neural network through the grid?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by 'differentiable', but here's a simple way to do it using advanced indexing.

```
coords = coords.long()
grid[coords[0],coords[1]] = 1

tensor([[1., 0., 1.],
        [0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 0., 1.]])
```

I think Torch doesn't have a detailed documentation about this, but `numpy` has [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html). (probably very similar for torch)

this is also possible

```
coords = coords.long()
grid[coords[0],coords[1]] = torch.Tensor([1,2,3,4])

tensor([[1., 0., 2.],
        [0., 0., 3.],
        [0., 0., 4.]])
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately this isn't differentiable either (i.e. gradients won't flow).

Comment: @duncster94 Oh now i get what you mean. Sry for that.

Answer (score 0):

Say

```
coords = [[0, 0, 1, 2],
         [0, 2, 2, 2]]
```

Then:

```
torch.stack([torch.stack(x) for x in coords])
```